# How do I add remote users to MySQL on OS X 10.6 Server?

Tags: mysql, mac-osx-server

I can't seem to connect to my remote MySQL server on my home network.

I have started the MySQL process on my Mac mini Server running 10.6.2 Snow Leopard Server.

I have downloaded Navicat lite to manage my database.

This works fine when I run Navicat on the actual server, it says connection successful.

When I run it from another machine though, giving it the server IP address, it says "Host '192.168.1.86' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server".

I have already commented out the "skip-networking" line of the my.cnf file.

I have also added the line "bind-address = 192.168.1.83" which is the address of my server (as advised by my googling for help).

Anything else I need to be doing? Basically I want to manage the server remotely.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to give mysql permissions for a user from that machine something like `grant SELECT, UPDATE, on database.* to user@192.168.1.68 identified by password;`

Comment: thanks Catherine. And I so this from the mysql> prompt yes?

Comment: Yes, from the mysql> prompt. Also, please note that there are a lot of place holders in that command.  You can get the full syntax of the command at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html